# Solve the Following series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to solve the following series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(3n+1)}$$
More generally, for $k \in \Bbb N$ Im trying to solve
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(kn+1)}$$
That way I would be able to solve
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+\frac{1}{k})}= k \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(kn+1)}$$
and by making $k \rightarrow \infty$ I will get a solution for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ which we know is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}= \frac{\pi ^2}{6}$$

Comment: Did you want the method or the answer?

Comment: both would be grate but i have a feeling the method is not easy to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(kn+1)} = \gamma + \psi\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)
$$
with digamma function $\psi(x)$ and Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$.
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(3n+1)} = 3 - \frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{3}} - \frac{3}{2}\log(3)
$$

Comment: amazing, thanks